# Is there a way to pause a Stripe payout?

Tags: stripe-payments

The use case is this; we have automated fraud detection in our system, and if we detect something that could cause money to be paid from Stripe to a bad actor, we want to pause the periodic Stripe payout from Stripe to the customer's bank account (eg: Stripe's "external account" for that customer).

There is a way to do this on the UI: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/pausing-payments-or-payouts-on-connected-accounts; dropdown on the right.  I'm looking for a way to do this with an API call.

Once the fraud has been investigated and deemed OK, our operations people will use the Stripe console above to manually un-pause/continue the payouts on the normal schedule.

I'm not an expert with the Stripe API but didn't see anything in the documentation that seemed the right thing.  Or even close, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you are currently managing Payouts, [Scheduling](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/manage-payout-schedule) or [Manual](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/manual-payouts).

If you are using the Scheduled approach your application can trigger a [change to the Connected Account](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update#update_account-settings-payouts-schedule-interval) when it detects something that *could be* fraud, setting the payout interval to `manual`.  This will pause any payouts unless you directly trigger them via the Dashboard or API.

You could also try [modifying `delay_days`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update#update_account-settings-payouts-schedule-delay_days) to give yourself a little more time to run your fraud checks and shorten them to the minimum again if/when everything checks out.

Of course, if you are using just Manual payouts then you would just not trigger the payout.

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  Our current management tack is Scheduled. Looks like changing to manual is the closest equivalent to the "pause" button on the Stripe UI.

Comment: Yeah that approach would allow you to toggle payouts on/off.  I would just test this out pretty thoroughly to ensure the behavior you expect.  Especially I would want to look into whether the switch to/from "manual" would affect the interval and day of the payout.

Comment: HI @RyanM
I would be appreciated if you share the result of you testing in regards of switch to/from "manual" would affect the interval and day of the payout?